# Conditionally chain a method?

Tags: php, oop

How do we conditionally chain methods in PHP? For example, this works fine:

```
$a->foo()->bar->baz->qux();
```

However, depending on a condition, I'd like to chain some methods but not others. Basically, shorten the following code:

```
if ($cond === true) {
    $a->foo()->baz();
} else {
    $a->foo()->bar();
}
```

Ideally something like the following would work:

```
$a->foo()
    ->bar()
    ($cond === true) ? ->baz() : ->qux()
    ->more();
```

Additionally, how would we conditionally chain a method (or not) depending on a condition? For example:

```
$a->foo()
    ->bar()
    if($cond === true) ->baz()
    ->more();
```

Comment: No need to obscure your code like that. There's 0 benefit for short notation apart from "looking cool" which is juvenile. Be better programmer than that if you're looking to learn.

Comment: @Weltschmerz In my particular case it's not a matter of looking cool, but I simply do not know how to use this class without doing something like this. So, it's more a matter of lack of knowledge and/or asking the wrong question. Next time I'll ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

The Self-Explanatory Mock-Snippet below (which you may [Quick-Test](https://eval.in/687327) Here) shows how you could do that

```
<?php   

    class Test{
        protected $prop1;
        protected $prop2;
        protected $prop3;
        protected $prop4;

        public function __construct() {
        }

        public function setProp1($prop1) {
            $this->prop1 = $prop1;
            return $this;
        }

        public function setProp2($prop2) {
            $this->prop2 = $prop2;
            return $this;
        }

        public function setProp3($prop3) {
            $this->prop3 = $prop3;
            return $this;
        }

        public function setProp4($prop4) {
            $this->prop3 = $prop4;
            return $this;
        }
    }

    $a      = 2;
    $b      = 7;
    $cond   = ($a > $b);
    $cond2  = ($b > 50);
    $test   = new Test;

    $test->setProp1(2)->{($cond  === true)  ? 'setProp4' : 'setProp3'}(11);
    $test->setProp3(3)->{($cond2 === false) ? 'setProp2' : 'setProp4'}(6);

    var_dump($test);
    //YIELDS::
    object(Test)[1]
      protected 'prop1' => int 2
      protected 'prop2' => int 6
      protected 'prop3' => int 3
      protected 'prop4' => null
```

Comment: The question (and answer) should also include if this is not less performant than just doing the if-then-else with repeating the class object and without chaining conditionally. Because now a string has to be interpreted, lined to a function and executed.  If it's less performant, I propose to add a small clausule in the beginning not to do this.

Comment: @e-motiv  That's why SO is all about Teamwork... Wouldn't hurt a bit if you could add that bit yourself - especially since you suggested it yourself as well...

Comment: Wouldn't hurt not to miss the "if" in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [variable methods (see example #2).](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) They allow you to do something like this:

```
class a {
    function foo() { echo '1'; return $this; }
    function bar() { echo '2'; return $this; }
    function baz() { echo '3'; return $this; }
}
$a = new a();

$cond = true;
$a->foo()->{($cond === true) ? 'baz' : 'bar'}();
// Prints 13
$cond = false;
$a->foo()->{($cond === true) ? 'baz' : 'bar'}();
// Prints 12
```

---

Here's a way that lets you set up requirements for each of the function calls. Note that this is just as hard to maintain as the previous solution, if not harder. You'll probably want to use some sort of configuration and the [`ReflectionClass's getMethods function`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php), too.

```
class a {
    function foo() { echo '1'; return $this; }
    function bar() { echo '2'; return $this; }
    function baz() { echo '3'; return $this; }
}

function evaluateFunctionRequirements($object, $functionRequirements, $condition) {
  foreach ($functionRequirements as $function=>$requirements) {
    foreach ($requirements as $requiredVariableName=>$requiredValue) {
      if (${$requiredVariableName} !== $requiredValue) {
        continue 2;
      }
    }
    $object->{$function}();
  }
}

$a = new a();
$functionRequirements = array('foo'=>array(), 'bar'=>array(), 'baz'=>array('condition'=>true));
$condition = true;
evaluateFunctionRequirements($a, $functionRequirements, $condition);
// Prints 123
$condition = false;
evaluateFunctionRequirements($a, $functionRequirements, $condition);
// Prints 12
```

Notes: This has the added *even harder to maintain* of requiring the functions in order for the `$functionRequirements` array. Additionally, this rudimentary example has only one possible condition var passed, update to another setup for getting more $requiredVariableName vars with [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php). You'll also want to verify that the methods passed in via $functionRequirements are [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) safe.

Comment: I would like to note that this is not very maintainable going forward. Say you need to refactor any of the method names, etc.

Comment: i dont think there's a better way ether 
he'll have to resort to eval (NOT RECOMMENDED) otherwise

Comment: @KevinStich Thank you, this is close! Also, I updated the question to include only chaining a specific method if a condition is met, otherwise don't. This is actually my specific use case today :)

Comment: @LookingToLearn make sure whoever maintains this code after you does not know where you live.

Comment: @zerkms Ha! I think it's maintainable, at least the form I'm writing now. I incorrectly asked this question so clarified it a bit (at the end).

Comment: Well, you cannot automatically refactor, IDEs would not able to search every place a function is invoked, the return type is lost, ... If that is "maintainable" - okay.

Comment: @zerkms You're assuming this code is one thing, while it's another. The desire in question simply chains a single method (or not), depending on a condition. This particular use case is simple.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything: what I stated are simply facts. But I'm not insisting for sure :-)

Comment: @zerkms okay, you are right. I was asking the wrong question based on my lack of knowledge. Thanks everyone, although I may end up deleting this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this by assigning the chaining to variable

```
$a = $a->foo();

if ($cond === true) {
   $a = $a->baz();
} else {
   $a = $a->bar();
}

$a->more();
```

Comment: simplest answer

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to create a method *when* (or name it whatever makes sense to you):

```php
    public function when($condition, $callback)
    {
        if ($condition) {
            return $callback($this) ?: $this;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Of course, you can extend it to accept additional arguments if you need to pass them to your methods *foo*, *bar*, etc...

And the usage with chaining would be:

```php
$a->when($cond === true, function ($a) {
    return $a->foo();
})->when($cond !== true, function ($a) {
    return $a->bar();
}
)->baz(); // a regular chaining method without condition
```